# Many sessions created on entering page instead of one. Why?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an application which utilizes Spring Boot + Spring MVC with Thymeleaf as view engine and I have noticed that when I enter login page (which is default landing page for app) many TCP sessions are created. Why is that? I believe that no session should be created at this stage, but after login, I should have only one session valid until I decide to logout. How to achieve this?

Below screenshot from WireShark:
[image]

Comment: Are you not confusing TCP session with a HTTP session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gimby was pointing out you are most likely confusing TCP sessions with HTTP sessions. Actually your screenshot does not show a "session" but the first two phases of the TCP three-way-handshake (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)) for reference. Most likely your login page contains links to additional JS and CSS files and possibly also some images that explain the multiple connections the browser is opening up.

Comment: Is there a way to omit this? I mean: download everything in single connection?

Comment: We'll not without changing the default behavior of your browser. What is your problem with this?

Comment: I have a problem with load balancer. I have following scenerio: There is a load balancer and behind him there are two frontend servers. Each of them talks with few backends. When load balancer is turned on, the response from backends seems to go to the wrong frontend, which causes, for example problem with logging in. Guy who is responsible for load balancer, told me that I should investigate those 6 tcp connections per request, as they may be the source of the problem. To be honest, I don't believe this is the cause, but have no other clue.

Comment: Ahh I see. Your issue sounds more like a problem of session stickiness cause you don't know about session state (logged in, etc.) in the other backend servers. If the lb balances based on a round robin algorithm the behavior you see is clear. But the solution is also quite easy: a) go for session stickiness on the lb and b) ensure that session data is exchanged between backend nodes, e.g. using Spring Session (http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/)